# Diffrence between two time stamp if hour greater than 24

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime, mktime

I just edit my question
I have have two time format i want the difference between them

For example

```
 $time1 = new DateTime('09:00:59');
 $time2 = new DateTime('100:30:00');
 $interval = $time1->diff($time2);
   echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s second(s)'); 
  ?>
```

Its working fine below 24 hour showing me fatal error if i am increasing time2

$time2 = new DateTime('100:30:00');

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (100:30:00) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character' in D:\xampp\htdocs\datetime.php:3 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\datetime.php(3): DateTime->__construct('100:30:00') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\datetime.php on line 3

Is there any other way or i can edit the same I have try a lot but not find out the soloution 
I just want the diffrence using any method
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your related code? - you've tagged `strtotime` but that is for timestamps, so 24 would be the cap as that is 12 midnight So you would need to include days?

Comment: You have to include the dates, you can subtract a timestamp from a timestamp without any conversion as long as you use the full timestamp so that php can determine the numerical value based on the UNIX epoc 1/1/1970.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/jasonlewis/expressive-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

```php
$time2 = '100:00:00';
$time1 = '10:30:00';

list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time2);
$interval2 = $hours*3600 + $minutes*60 + $seconds;

list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time1);
$interval1 = $hours*3600 + $minutes*60 + $seconds;

$diff = $interval2 - $interval1;

echo floor($diff / 3600) . ':' . 
     str_pad(floor($diff / 60) % 60, 2, '0') . ':' . 
     str_pad($diff % 60, 2, '0');
```

Output:

```
89:30:00
```

Here is **[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Do0KSN)** demo

Answer (score 1):

I Hope this may help.

```
$time1 = '10:30:00';
$time2 = '100:00:00';


function hms2sec ($hms) {
    list($h, $m, $s) = explode (":", $hms);
    $seconds = 0;
    $seconds += (intval($h) * 3600);
    $seconds += (intval($m) * 60);
    $seconds += (intval($s));
    return $seconds;
}
$ts1=hms2sec($time2);
$ts2=hms2sec($time1);
$time_diff = $ts1-$ts2;

function seconds($seconds) {

        // CONVERT TO HH:MM:SS
        $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
        $remainder_1 = ($seconds % 3600);
        $minutes = floor($remainder_1 / 60);
        $seconds = ($remainder_1 % 60);

        // PREP THE VALUES
        if(strlen($hours) == 1) {
            $hours = "0".$hours;
        }

        if(strlen($minutes) == 1) {
            $minutes = "0".$minutes;
        }

        if(strlen($seconds) == 1) {
            $seconds = "0".$seconds;
        }

        return $hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;

        }
echo $final_diff=seconds($time_diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough "reputation" to add a comment to the selected answer. I want to add a message to point out to a flaw with it.

If you try it with these arguments:

```
$time2 = '10:15:00';
$time1 = '10:10:00';
```

You will get an incorrect result of:
    0:50:00

To correct this, you need to add STR_PAD_LEFT within the str_pad that deals with the minute as in:

```
str_pad(floor($diff / 60) % 60, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' .
```